# How to remove part of text from text gotten from webelement?

Tags: python, arrays, selenium, selenium-webdriver, replace

How do you remove part of text after you get it from the webpage

```py
matchname = (WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='text-nowrap text-truncate text-muted']"))))
print(matchname.text)
```

The output of code looks like this : `clubname1 vs clubname 2`.
I want to remove `vs` part of it so it only outputs :  `clubname1 clubname2`

I tried using numpy.char.lstrip(array, chars=value) to remove "vs" from text, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can applay `replace()` method on received string replacing the unwanted substring with nothing, as following:

```py
matchname_text = (WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='text-nowrap text-truncate text-muted']")))).text
wanted_text = matchname_text.replace('vs','')
```